# String cannot be cast to org.JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I have this piece of code that was working and all of a sudden is now throwing a Cast Exception. Have anyone experienced something similar? Thanks.

```
@Override
public List<RecordJSONclass> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
        throws IOException {
    List<RecordJSONclass> result = new ArrayList<RecordJSONclass>();
    String JSONResponse = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);

    try {
        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(JSONResponse).nextValue();
        JSONObject earthquakes = object.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray temp = earthquakes.getJSONArray("temperature");
        JSONArray prob = earthquakes.getJSONArray("pop");
```

is throwing a

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   org.json.JSONObject
>   at myxmlparser.ResponseHandlerJSON.handleResponse(ResponseHandlerJSON.java:22)

The exception happens at line

> JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new
>   JSONTokener(JSONResponse).nextValue();

however a String is passed as example in the Class overview in http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is the return value. The `nextValue` method does not return a `JSONObject`. It returns a `String` in this case.

From the Javadoc:

> Object    nextValue() - Returns the next value from the input.

So, you can't assume that it is a `JSONObject`.

So, to get hold of the correct value simply use:

```
String val = (String) new JSONTokener(JSONResponse).nextValue();
```

Comment: You are correct wassgren. Thanks for the reply. The HttpResponse response was coming null due to malformed URL from the calling method.